# Вставка в поле "Многострочный текст"

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple

Подскажите пожалуйста как доработать текст в переменной `var dummyContent` с помощью JS или JQuery, чтобы его можно было через copy\past кодом вставить в поле "Многострочный текст", при этом чтобы текст добавлялся нормально, с тегами и сохранялся. не судите строго, много примеров перебрал, ничего не подходит. Код:

```js
function copy() {
  var dummyContent = 'Hello world';
  var dummy = $('<input>').val(dummyContent).appendTo('body').select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="Copyitem" value="Копировать текст" onclick="copy();">
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Где поле "многострочный текст"? О каких тэгах речь? В чем вообще проблема и почему не устраивает существующий код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `textarea` для многострочного инпута и символ новой строки `'\n'` внутри строки:

```js
function copy() {
  var dummyContent = 'Hello world\nWorld hello';
  var dummy = $('<textarea>')
      .val(dummyContent)
      .css("font-family", "Verdana")
      .css("font-size", "20px")
      .appendTo('body').select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="Copyitem" value="Копировать текст" onclick="copy();">
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример, '/n' полезно, но не все...есть варианты как данному тексту применить шрифт и добавить к примеру ссылки на URL?

Comment: Обновил код, добавил изменение шрифта и его размера. 
Гиперссылку вы в инпут никак не вставите, эти объекты предназначаются для внесения изменения в текст. 
Советую смотреть в сторону HTML-редакторов, такие как tinyMCE.

Comment: Спасибо, но если копирую твой текст и вставляю в Многострочный текст, размер текста и шрифты не применяются, актуальна только сноска "\n".

Comment: @Melvin Это логично, так как за смену там отвечают два фрагмента кода: `.css("font-family", "Verdana")` и `.css("font-size", "20px")`. Они задают аттрибуты `textarea` и в последствии не изменяются.

Comment: А мне нужна возможность вставки текста с готовыми шрифтами и разметкой в столбец "Многострочный текст".

Comment: @MelviN "Советую смотреть в сторону HTML-редакторов, такие как tinyMCE."

Comment: Спасибо, а есть такой вопрос: у меня есть 1-страница, на ней есть таблица (обычный html) и 2-страница, на ней есть кнопка...как мне реализовать копирование таблицы из страницы 1 и вставка ее на страницу 2 (вставка дополнительных тегов на страницу 2 нерекомендовано)?

Comment: Советую вам создать отдельный вопрос, так больше вероятность что его увидят те кто в этом хорош. (Или поискать существующий ответ, возможно такой вопрос уже был создан)